# Java check if 2 arrays have any matching items or all items

Tags: java

I want to check in Java if two arrays either have one of the same items or all of the items in the other array.

My setup is like this:

A model class which I am using to determine an item.

```java
public class Item {
  @Getter
  private int id;

  public Item(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

A manager class which I am using which contains some items.

```java
public class Manager {
  @Getter
  private Item[] items = {
    new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)
  }
}
```

I have tried to implement a method called `hasItem` but whenever it runs, it doesn't seem to resolve if there is any existing.

```
public class Manager {
  ...

  
  private boolean hasItem(int[] searchableIds, boolean requiresAll) {
    final Stream<Item> streamedItems = Arrays.stream(items);
    HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton(searchableIds));

    if (requiresAll) {
      // Make sure the items are identical.
      return streamedItems.map(Item::getId).filter(ids::contains).count() == searchableIds.length;
    }

    return streamedItems.map(Item::getId).anyMatch(ids::contains);
  }
}
```

The goal is - if requiresAll is passed in as `true`, then it'll ensure that *all* the items are contained within the `streamedItems` variable. If it is `false` then it'll just see if there's any matches within.

Comment: Try using a simple for loop.

Comment: I did originally do that but I didn't know if there was a more convenient way rather than doing the for loop. If that's all I can do, I will revert from this approach.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `streamedItems` instead of `items`?

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo. Will edit now.

Comment: You are declaring a HashSet<int> but you are assigning to it a HashSet<int[]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do the trick:

```java
        private boolean hasItem(Integer[] searchableIds, boolean requiresAll) {
            final Set<Integer> available = Arrays.stream(items).map(it -> it.id).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            final Set<Integer> searched = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(searchableIds));

            return requiresAll
                    ? available.containsAll(searched)
                    : !Collections.disjoint(available, searched);
        }
```

But you should use two methods instead of one single method with a flag. It is a code smell.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! In terms of the code smell, would you do a method `hasItem` and another method `requiresAllItems()` ?

Comment: Yes. IMHO I would probably name them `hasItem` and `hasAllItems`.

Answer (score 0):

Always try simple for loops first.

But if you want to use streams you can use the below code for reference:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Item {
    private int id;
    
    public Item(int id_) {
        this.id = id_;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item[] available = {new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)};
        int[] toSearch = {1,2};
        Set<Integer> ids = Arrays.stream(toSearch).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        
        var streamedAvailable = Arrays.stream(available);
        var num = streamedAvailable.map(x -> x.getId())
                        .filter(x -> ids.contains(x))
                        .count();
        System.out.println(num);

        var streamedAvailable2 = Arrays.stream(available);
        var res = streamedAvailable2.map(x -> x.getId())
                        .anyMatch(x -> ids.contains(x));
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

But it seems you want intersection of two arrays. Just use `Set::retainAll` like this:

```
Set<Type> intersection = new HashSet<Type>(s1);
intersection.retainAll(s2);
```

Then just check the size of `intersection`. If greater than 1, then there is some match. If equal to size of s2, then complete match.